# deugging login error canvas app - rails - facebooker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebooker

I have inherited an app set up using built using rails using the facebooker gem. It's hosted on heroku.

I'm getting  reports of users getting the following error when they try and grant permissions -

An error occurred with . Please try again later.

I've had a look through heroku's logs and can't see any errors.

Any advice on how I should debug  this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question. I presume no one else will due to the abysmal lack of information that I provided.

the reason I'd not encountered this error before was because Facebook forced a relocation of apps to secure servers recently.

I'd neglected to change my app url in my login javascript to 'https'

Firefox & chrome did not notice the difference. Internet explorer 7 did.

In a nutshell - make sure you have the correct domain name in your facebook app settings.